# Using in_array to control output of forum post categories

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a forum for internal use at my work.

I have categories set for the posts because I want the ability to control what categories people see.

The output code is:

```
$data_query = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE deleted = 'no' ORDER BY id DESC");
```

What I was thinking would be something like this:

```
 $cat_query = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT subs FROM users WHERE  username='$userLoggedIn'");
    $cat_array = mysqli_fetch_array($cat_query);
    $c_arr = explode(",", $cat_array);
    $post_cat = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT post_category FROM posts WHERE deleted='no'");

if(in_array($post_cat, $c_arr){
$data_query = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE (post_category=$post_cat AND deleted = 'no') ORDER BY id DESC");
}
```

However, when I do this, it doesn't work.

Basically I need the data_query to only return the posts with categories in the categories array.  This I cannot figure out.

EDIT:  Table Structure within Database

users table:

```
   CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `signup_date` date NOT NULL,
  `profile_pic` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `num_posts` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `num_likes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_closed` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `friend_array` text NOT NULL,
  `city` text NOT NULL,
  `state` text NOT NULL,
  `country` text NOT NULL,
  `subs` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

posts table:

```
   CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `body` text NOT NULL,
  `added_by` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `user_to` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `user_closed` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `deleted` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `likes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_category` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Hope this helps

Comment: why not use `WHERE post_category IN()` clause in SQL.

Comment: So...
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_category IN('$c_arr')...

Comment: So, no, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE (post_category IN ($c_arr) AND deleted = 'no') ORDER BY id DESC" doesn't seem to work, nor does putting single quotes around $c_arr.  Neither does using the unexploded $cat_array variable.

Maybe I should state that the $cat_array is from the users table where the post_category is from the posts table.  Does that make a difference?

Comment: You should probably not have multiple entries in your `subs` field, this is bad database design.

Comment: With 7 different categories, how would you suggest I change to allow multiple categories to be displayed?

Answer (score 1):

Try to write your logic in one query and don't use php functions when you can do your logic in database side

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE deleted='no' AND post_category IN (SELECT subs FROM users WHERE  username='$userLoggedIn' ORDER BY id DESC)";
$result = mysqli_query($this->con, $query);
```

**EDIT:**

First of all I would say that it is very bad practice to store comma separated strings' list in a single row, you should create new table for `subs`.

but in this case you should do this:

```
 <?php
 $cat_query = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT subs FROM users WHERE  username='$userLoggedIn'");
 if($cat_query){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($car_query);
    $subs = $row['subs'];

    $post_cat_query = "SELECT post_category FROM posts WHERE deleted='no'";
    $result = mysqli_query($this->con, $post_cat_query);

    if($result){
        $c_arr = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            array_push($c_arr, $row['post_category']);
        }

        if(in_array($post_cat, $c_arr){
            $data_query = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE (post_category=$post_cat AND deleted = 'no') ORDER BY id DESC");

    }


 }
```

Comment: This works FINE when there's only one category in the subs column.  But adding a second category it doesn't show anything

Comment: you use select it from users table right? there is only user logged in, so how many subs could written in a single row of 'subs' column?

Comment: Currently I have up to 7 different post categories that there is to choose from.  And if someone has chosen multiple categories, then the forum should only display posts that share tags within the users.subs table column

Comment: Users use check boxes to determine what gets stored in the subs column and it's stored as an array

Comment: I'm not interested in your user interface, I wonder structure of tables you use here. It would be good if you edit your question and describe your tables well. In this case I could answer you correctly what you need

Comment: @Godot I have updated the question to include the table structure, hopefully that helps!

Comment: ok, it's all clear but I have one more question: can you write down one example of 'subs' row? Do you have in this row long varchar where is listed your subs separated with commas?

Comment: @Godot so, for example "BusFin,Entertainment,Food,Politics" would be an example of what is stored within one of the subs (mine specifically)

Comment: I changed my answer, take a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164807/discussion-between-aaron-barksdale-and-godot).

Comment: that didn't seem to work.  I'm trying a new tactic.

Thank you for all your help.